# How to set number of Map tasks in hadoop Job class

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper

I have a problem to set number of mappers to one through Java. I am using Job and configuration class. I know that we can set the number of reducers through `mapred.map.tasks` with old deprecated API.

Is there any way to specify that using Job and configuration classes. I tried by increasing the input file split size using  `FileInputFormat.setMinInputSplitSize(FullFilesize)`

But, I would like to know do we have any equivalent to the `mapred.map.tasks` in the new API or how do you specify by other way

Comment: do you want all your input to go to one mapper or you want only 1 mapper to run at a time?

Comment: @vishnuviswanath   Yes, that's what my problem at hand needs

Comment: Which of the above 2? All input to 1 job or run only one mapper at a time

Comment: I want to run only one mapper(totally)

Comment: how many input files do you have?

Comment: @vishnuviswanath one

Comment: check these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831303/one-mapper-or-a-reducer-to-process-one-file-or-directory/8831737#comment55266183_8831737  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969517/hadoop-non-splittable-textinputformat

Answer (score 0):

The number of map tasks for a given job is driven by the number of input splits and not by the mapred.map.tasks parameter

refer following stack over flow question 
[Setting the number of map tasks and reduce tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885441/setting-the-number-of-map-tasks-and-reduce-tasks)